# How to properly redirect to another site without breaking the browser back button?

Tags: python, http, redirect, pylons

I am trying to make a redirection from a python app to another site. I am currently doing it in the controller which works just fine but breaks the back browser button.

I know that a redirection with meta refresh or js, will allow me to add a delay so the user will have time to go back but I read everywhere that these techniques are deprecated and better be avoided.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the back browser button"? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: I guess they mean that user is going 'back' and just get redirected again, which is annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is sending HTTP status code 302 instead of 200 and adding `Location: <url>` to response headers. How to do this depends on the WEB framework you are running your Python app on.

Comment: Thank you! The framework is pylons and the following code does the trick:  
  
    response.status_int = 302  
    response.headers['location'] = 'http://google.com'